# How can i import jquery in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a website and I want to use jquery. But I can't import jquery in javascript.How can I import Jquery in a javascript file ?

Comment: No,I am asking that how can i import jquery in a js file ?

Comment: Cannot you use the `import` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Just add this in title of your main HTML file and then you would have access to `$` which can be called from anywhere by any script which is linked to the HTML file.